# deleting a specific item from a java LL

Tags: java, linked-list

So I'm trying to delete an item from a linked list in java.I'm not using java's predefined LL but I'm working with my own.

I know the concept to delete an item is to traverse in the link and compare the data in the list one by one.

so here's what I came up with, but it doesn't work!

```
public void delStudent(int regN) {
    Node current = head;
    Node q = head;

    if (current.getStudent().getRegN() == regN) {
        head = head.link;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (current.getStudent().getRegN() != regN) {
                current = current.link;
                q = current;
            }
        }
        q.link= current.link.link;

    }
```

Comment: Why your `Node` class has those methods?

Comment: MyLinkedList class has this method, my Node class just has a Student data type and another node for a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your list is empty, the execution of the if statement in the beginning will immediately give a NullPointerException (because current will be null). Generally, for the LinkedList delete method, you must consider three cases: size == 0, size == 1, and size > 1 (where size is the number of nodes in the Linked List).

```
public void delStudent(int regN) {
    Node current = head;
    Node previous = head;       
    while (current != null ){ // keep traversing till end of list
        if (current.getStudent().getRegN() == regN) { // found it!
            previous.link = current.link; // relink
            if (current == head){ // edge case : removed first element
                head = current.link; // move head forward.
            }
            break;
        } else {
            previous = current;
            current = current.link;
        }   
    }
}
```

The above code assumes regN is unique and that there is only one student with that regN. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm really thankful for this!! I've been working on it for a really long time!! The thing is I know how to solve the problem but I couldn't type out the code! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is (I think) in these three lines:

```
current = current.link;
q = current;
```

(where you set `q` to be the same as `current`) and

```
q.link= current.link.link;
```

(and maybe also in using `length()` depending on it's implementation)

To see why let's look at how to delete in more detail: 
Let's consider there are three nodes in your list x->y->z and you want to delete y. 
In order to do so you need to set `x.link = z`.

To return to you example it means that the variable `q` should store the element before `current`, then deleting `current` can be done by

```
q.link = current.link;
```

In order order to have `q` be the predecessor of `current` you have to reverse the two lines above, i.e., use

```
q = current;
current = current.link;
```

Why am I saying depending on the implementation of `length` ? If you implementation of length just returns some number maintained by increasing whenever you add a value to the list, you should also decrement it when deleting one. If length traverses the list in order to find the number of elements then its ok, although not very efficient.

One last comment: your code will *not work* (even with the fixes I explain above) when there is no element with the given `regN`. Why? Because you always delete one element. Moreover, you might want to rethink the logic inside the loop. Currently if the element to delete is the second one and there is 1000000 elements you will run the loop nearly 1000000 times.

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking each node you need to delete the node or break once you find a match. You need to maintain a node for the previous node to be able to delete the current node once you find a match.

I just realized that you were attempting to to that with Node q

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (current.getStudent().getRegN() != regN) {
        q = current;
        current = current.link;           
    } else{ //we have a match
        //remove the link to the current item
        q.link = current.link; 
        break; 
    }
```

if you are using a doubly linked list you can use node.prev().link = current.link;

Comment: shouldn't there be a loop for us to use the "break" ?

Comment: Yes. This would still be inside of the for loop

Comment: right, but when I run this it gives me a null pointer exception, you see i have 3 students with regN from 1-3 respectively , when I call the method with 1 it gives an exception. but when I call it with 2 it deletes the node at position 2 and it's not supposed to do that, it should delete the node of holding the regN  2

Comment: no im not using a doubly linked list..it's just a normal list